# Meaning of "he has done little to make the case to leaders that stacking political institutions with tycoons and their cronies will fuel discontent"

Tags: meaning, sentence

> When it comes to political reform, Mr Leung's hands are tied by Mr Xi's intransigence.
>   **But he has done little to make the obvious case to leaders in Beijing that stacking political institutions with tycoons and their cronies will fuel discontent.**
>   The Occupy demonstrators wanted not just a one-person, one-vote electoral system, but also a sweeping change in the way that Hong Kong has been ruled for more than 170 years.

I can't understand the bold sentence. What does that mean?

Comment: It means Leung Chung-ying hasn't done enough to convince Xi Jin-ping that placing financial elites in high-ranking government positions in Hong Kong is making Hong-Kongers unhappy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But he has done little
>   {to make the obvious case = **to present the obvious reasons**}
>   to leaders in Beijing
>   that {stacking = **selectively filling**}
>   political institutions
>   with {tycoons = **wealthy businessmen**}
>   and {their cronies = **their friends/relatives/business partners**}
>   will {fuel discontent ≈ **give [ordinary] people reasons to be dissatisfied**}.

Comment: One must take their hat off to you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - For some reason, I am now eating a red shirt. The doll was yummy!